# Recovering deleted files from unrooted Android device requires factory data reset

Tags: rooting, data-recovery, bootloader-lock, motorola

I would like to create a copy of the internal drive (not SD) of my Android device (Motorola E3) to recover some deleted files, but it requires rooting of the device. Rooting itself requires bootloader unlocking. During bootloader unlocking one has to wipe the internal drive (text taken from the "Unlock bootloader" menu):

> To prevent unauthoritzed access to your personal data, unlocking the bootloader will also **delete all personal data** from your phone (a "factory data reset").

It sounds a bit contradictory to me. Is there no way to restore deleted files even after rooting the device?

**Note:** These answers (and many others on the internet) were not helpful:

- [Moto G -- recovering files after bootloader unlock (wipe)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89782/moto-g-recovering-files-after-bootloader-unlock-wipe)
- [Recovering deleted files from unrooted Galaxy Nexus](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35640/recovering-deleted-files-from-unrooted-galaxy-nexus)
- [How Recover deleted data from internal memory of non rooted Moto G device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110449/how-recover-deleted-data-from-internal-memory-of-non-rooted-moto-g-device)
- Advices like "download *<fancy-tool-xy.exe>* and root the device" without explaining what that tool exactly does (apart from this that fancy tool would probably contain some malware)

Comment: The real problem here is all these tutorials are for back when you could directly access the internal storage via USB, and you just can't do that anymore, regardless of root, instead we use MTP now. All these things your looking require direct drive access which isn't possible in modern Android devices. If you can't download and use a simple recovery tool from the Play Store, your likely just out of luck. And rooting is more difficult than it was back then, you must unlock the bootloader which will wipe the device, and since it uses encryption out of the box everything would be lost forever

Comment: Your device is a little aged, I assume it runs with Android 6 or 7. The only chance I see to get root without unlocking the bootloader would be using a root exploit from within an app. I am not sure but I assume that there are some root exploits that work on your old phone that would make this possible and would gain you (temporary) root permissions. Unfortunately using a root exploit usually requires you to run some "fancy tools" you never know what exactly it is doing.

Comment: @Robert If exploit code for priv. escalation is public it would be ok too